# Make git rebase print commit ids

Tags: git, rebase

I am doing a git rebase, and the output is something like this:

> Applying: Issue #163: blablabla
>   Applying: Issue #130: blablabla
>   Applying: Issue #130: blablabla
>   [..]
>   CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in path/to/file

When resolving conflicts in a rebase, I like to use `git show` to look at the original commit being picked.

But with this output, I do not see any commit ids.

Is there any way to make git show the commit ids?

PS: I think it does work with interactive rebase, but why would this make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in looking at the current commit being merged, the one which is introducing conflicts, you could run the following:

`git rebase --show-current-patch`

Or:

`git show REBASE_HEAD`

Which does the same thing.
If you'd then like to look at the commit that was successfully applied right before it, you could run:

`git show REBASE_HEAD~1`

You can read more at

> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---show-current-patch

Comment: And `git log REBASE_HEAD` to show the history of that commit. Thanks!